# How to download the zip file, Reads Zip archives with no intermediate disk/memory storage in servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, zip, download

I have one zip file (`C:\source.zip` ~130 mb size) common source in my server, I want to create new text file that depends on user info dynamically and append into that `source.zip`, then I need to give a download link to separate user.

My idea is, I will combine the source.zip and new user text file into one temporary folder (`c:\temp`). Then I will give the temporary folder as download link. After user downloaded the zip, I will delete the zip file in temp folder.

But my problem is, I will duplicate source into temp folder. So many users access this means server size will increase. So I want to read the (`source.zip` and text file) zip archives with no intermediate disk/memory storage to download in servlet.

How can I do this in servlet or jsp?

Comment: You can always offload your work to the client ... http://stuk.github.io/jszip/

Comment: Drejc @ i used jszip, but its suit for small size files. My zip file size is 130mb. So browser got crashed

Comment: Try looking for some other JavaScript lib ... maybe this will work. 130mb is not that large that it could'n be handled by the browser. If this wan't work you will probably have to go the server way. Maybe if you create a special servlet on a separate machine to handle those requests.